# How to compute the unique MLE from an Exponential Family of Distributions?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let 
$$
f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{e^{\theta x}\cos(\theta \pi/2)}{\cosh(x)}, x\in{\mathbb{R}}
$$
be a family of densities and which is clearly exponential family.

Then what is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\hat\theta_{n}$ of $\theta$ based on an independent sample of size $n$?

My try:

When I solved the loglikelihood equation, I got 
$$
\tan(\theta \pi/2)=\frac{2}{\pi}\bar{x} \hspace 4cm (*)
$$

Now, my problem is, if we solve $(*)$ for $\hat\theta_{n}$ then $\hat\theta_{n}$ is not unique. But for the exponential family it should be unique, right? So, I don't understand what is going wrong here. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote is not a density function for any value of $\theta$.  It isn't even nonnegative over the support you stated, so I don't know how you can claim it's "clearly" from the exponential family.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo and I fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Still wrong.  Over the entire real line, for $-1 < \theta < 1$, the density you wrote integrates to $2$, not $1$.  If we drop the $2$, then the MLE is given by $$\hat\theta = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \tanh x_i.$$

Comment: No, we need to integrate w.r.t. $x$ not w.r.t.$\theta$. You know, $\theta$ is a parameter.

Comment: I **did** integrate it with respect to $x$.  That is what I meant by "Over the entire real line."  But the integral is conditionally convergent for parameter values $-1 < \theta < 1$.  Don't believe me?  Integrate $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{e^{\theta x} \cos \frac{\pi \theta}{2}}{\cosh x} \, dx.$$  This integral converges **iff** $\theta \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Oho! I don't see it, could you please explain the details?

Comment: No.  Not until you are able to correctly state the question, provide a correct density function.  Otherwise, you are wasting my time.

Comment: The density is correct, just see Exercise 8.4 on p. 138 of this book:

http://ksu.edu.sa/sites/py/ar/mpy/departments/math/learnResources/ResourceCenter/Documents/Cambridge%20University%20Press%20-%20Essentials%20of%20statistical%20inference.pdf

Comment: Even if we remove 2 then how do you get,
$$
\hat{\theta_{n}}=(1/n)\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n tanh(x_{i})
$$

Comment: Yes, I fixed the density should be as edited now.

Comment: @ heropup: Your MLE 
$$
\hat{\theta_{n}}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\tan{h}(x_{i})
$$
does not make any sense at all to me.

Comment: To sum up: the function $f(\ ;\theta)$ must be integrable (otherwise it is not a density), this forces $|\theta|\lt1$, then there is only one value of $\theta$ such that $\tan(\theta\pi/2)$ is what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint density is $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{\theta x_i} \cos \frac{\pi}{2}\theta}{\pi \cosh x_i} = \biggl(\frac{\cos \tfrac{\pi}{2} \theta}{\pi}\biggr)^{\!n} \exp(\theta n \bar x) \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\cosh x_i}.$$  Thus the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = n \log \cos \tfrac{\pi}{2}\theta - n \log \pi + n \theta \bar x - \sum_{i=1}^n \log \cosh x_i.$$  The derivative with respect to $\theta$ is $$\frac{d\ell}{d\theta} = -n \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \tan \frac{\pi}{2} \theta +  \bar x\right).$$  This gives the critical point $$\hat \theta = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1} \frac{2}{\pi} \bar x.$$

*Note that my previous computation was incorrect*.

This is a unique MLE because the inverse tangent is taken to be in the range $(-\tfrac{\pi}{2}, \tfrac{\pi}{2})$, since we are required to have $-1 < \theta < 1$:  the density is negative if $|\theta| \ge 1$.  Therefore, there is exactly one $\hat \theta \in (-1,1)$ for any given $\bar x$.

Comment: +1. Indeed the function $f(\ ;\theta)$ is a density if and only $|\theta|\lt1$ (and the answer to bring to the OP reduces to this fact, imho). The argument in your post (based on the sign of $f(\ ;\theta)$) is not sufficient since it fails for $3\lt\theta\lt5$, say. Rather, one can appeal to the **integrability** of $f(\ ;\theta)$, which holds if and only if $|\theta|\lt1$ (and then the sign condition comes for free).

Comment: For some reason I mentioned the integrability condition in my comment, and then I didn't in my answer...  *shrug*  O_o

Comment: OK. Actually everything in your answer before the three last lines seems to simply redo what the OP explains, no?

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to explicitly confirm that that is the correct MLE, rather than what I had written earlier in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm... I now see there were some edits to the post that I was not aware of. Maybe this explains that you give the computations in your post before the three last lines.

Comment: There is a sign typo $\frac{dl}{d\theta}=-n(...-...)$. There should be $-$ instead of $+$.